# Python Data Cleaning with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

My dataset looks like this

```
Name    Subset            Value
A       67-A-5678          14
A       58-ABC-87555       187
A       45-ASH-87954       5465
S       34-A-8785          454
S       58-ASO-98978       54
S       23-ASH-87895       784
X       98-X-87876         455
X       87-ABC-54578       4545
X       56-ASH-89667       854
Y       09-D-98644         45
Y       87-ABC-78834       98
Y       87-ASH-87455A      4566
L       67-A-87545         78
L       89-GHS-08753       12 
L       78-PHU-09876       655
```

I want to keep only those groups of rows whose "subset" columns are of pattern; `*`, `*ABC`, `*ASH` (Note: `*` is any alphabet or digit).

For example, output should look like

```
Name    Subset             Value
A       67-A-5678          14
A       58-ABC-87555       187
A       45-ASH-87954       5465
X       98-X-87876         455
X       87-ABC-54578       4545
X       56-ASH-89667       854
Y       09-D-98644         45
Y       87-ABC-78834       98
Y       87-ASH-87455A      4566
```

P.S. Actual dataset can be of many columns/rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
filtered = df[df.groupby('Name')['Subset'].transform(lambda x: len(x) >= 3 and'-ABC-' in x.iloc[1] and '-ASH-' in x.iloc[2])]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
   Name         Subset  Value
0     A      67-A-5678     14
1     A   58-ABC-87555    187
2     A   45-ASH-87954   5465
6     X     98-X-87876    455
7     X   87-ABC-54578   4545
8     X   56-ASH-89667    854
9     Y     09-D-98644     45
10    Y   87-ABC-78834     98
11    Y  87-ASH-87455A   4566
```

Comment: Please check the edited question

Comment: Trying to use; filter(lambda group: group['Subset'].str.match( r'\d+-[ABC,ASH]+-\d').all())

Comment: @SHLOK I'm sorry, I forgot about this question! :) Please check now.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Please go through this as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/70966309/17778275