# Checking different elements of a cell in dataframe separated by comma using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three dataframes [Accepted, Ignored, Input]. We have to check the "Subset" column strings of Input df in the subset columns of accepted and ignored df. If the subset are not present in both of them, we have to keep them in exception.
[Strings should match exactly]]
For eg.

Accepted df is

```
Accepted   Accepted  
AC         ASD
ZX         AGH
```

Ignored df is

```
Ignored    Ignored
AD         ADS
```

Input df is

```
Name    Subset
Apple   AC,AC,AD,AGH
Bat     ZX,ADS,AXC
Cat     HJ,AGH
```

Output we need:

```
 Name    Subset        Accepted    Ignored     Exception
 Apple   AC,AC,AD,AGH  AC,AC,AGH   AD
 Bat     ZX,ADS,AXC    ZX          ADS         AXC
 Cat     HJ,AGH        AGH                     HJ
```

All the dataframes can have multiple rows and columns.

How can I do it using Python.

Comment: What is your current approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `accepted`, `ignored`, and `inp` the input dataframes, you can achieve this by reshaping your dataframe and mapping from a dictionary:

```
cat = (pd.concat({'Accepted': accepted, 'Ignored': ignored})
       .stack()
       .reset_index()
       .set_index(0)['level_0'].to_dict()
    )
# {'AC': 'Accepted', 'ASD': 'Accepted', 'ZX': 'Accepted',
#  'AGH': 'Accepted', 'AD': 'Ignored', 'ADS': 'Ignored'}

(inp.assign(col=inp['Subset'].str.split(','))
    .explode('col')
    .assign(value=lambda d: d['col'].map(lambda x: cat.get(x, 'Exception')))
    .pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Subset'], columns='value', values='col',
                 aggfunc=','.join, fill_value='')
    .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
    Name      Subset Accepted Exception Ignored
0  Apple   AC,AD,AGH   AC,AGH                AD
1    Bat  ZX,ADS,AXC       ZX       AXC     ADS
2    Cat      HJ,AGH      AGH        HJ
```

Comment: It gives a KeyError: 'Subset2'.
P.S My Accepted and Ignored dataframe have no column names.

Comment: @SHLOK They necessarily have column names. It might be 0/1/... numbers. Make sure you use that instead. Check the names with `accepted.columns`, etc.

Comment: I have multiple columns in the accepted and ignored columns.
I will name all the columns as Accepted in accepted df and Ignored in ignored df. What should I edit in the code then.

Comment: Check the edited column names in the question.

Comment: @SHLOK can you try to rename the columns as it showed in your first version of the question? It is quite a trivial change

Comment: Should I rename my dataset with those names?

Comment: @SHLOK ideally yes, in any case avoid duplicated column names

Comment: It's the need of my project actually.

Comment: @SHLOK check the update, the names actually don't matter, I had used the wrong value name in `pivot_table`

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/71438823/17778275

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/71577325/17778275

Answer (score 2):

Use sets for get intersection and difference in splitted values by `,`, last join back to strings by `join`:

```
Accepted = set(df1.to_numpy().ravel())
Ignored = set(df2.to_numpy().ravel())
Both = set.union(Accepted,Ignored)

df['Accepted'] = df['Subset'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(Accepted & set(x.split(','))))
df['Ignored'] = df['Subset'].apply(lambda x:  ','.join(Ignored & set(x.split(','))))
df['Exception'] = df['Subset'].apply(lambda x:  ','.join(set(x.split(',')) - Both))

print (df)
    Name      Subset Accepted Ignored Exception
0  Apple   AC,AD,AGH   AC,AGH      AD          
1    Bat  ZX,ADS,AXC       ZX     ADS       AXC
2    Cat      HJ,AGH      AGH                HJ
```

Comment: FYI, I had a similar solution and restarted with a completely different approach ;)

Comment: Hey I am getting the required output, but cannot get all the instances divided into accepted, ignored and exception.

For eg. Lets say, in input dataframe as above, "Subset" column for Apple is AC,AC,AD,AGH.
Then in "Accepted" column of output, I need AC,AC,AGH.
But I am getting only AC,AGH. Kindly suggest a way.

Comment: Please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/q/71577325/17778275

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do with vanilla lists.

```
accepted_list = [item for sublist in accepted_df.values.tolist() for item in sublist]
ignored_list = [item for sublist in ignored_df.values.tolist() for item in sublist]

input_df["Subset"] = input_df["Subset"].apply(lambda x: x.split(","))
input_df["Accepted"] = input_df["Subset"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in accepted_list])
input_df["Ignored"] = input_df["Subset"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in ignored_list])
input_df["Exception"] = input_df["Subset"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i not in accepted_list + ignored_list])
```

Basically checking if members in our list are/not in other list. If you want to keep in a string, you can join the members of the list by "'".join as jezrael suggested.

Comment: This gives me comma separated characters like A,C,A,D,A,G,H and so on. Everything is going into exception hence.