# Extracting the first instance of alphabetical string from an alphanumeric string in a dataframe cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataframe, data-extraction

I have this dataset:

```
NAME    SUBSET 
Apple   48 – ABC – HH
Bat     72 – ACD – HH, 72 – FI, 36 – FE – PP 
Cat     ABC, 72 – AA – LL
```

From this data, I want to extract only the first instance of alphabet occurrence and omit the remaining part i.e. I want the output of the form:

```
NAME      SUBSET
Apple     ABC
Bat       ACD, FI, FE
Cat       ABC, AA
```

How will I be able to do it in Python? Please guide.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with `extractall` and aggregate:

```
df['SUBSET'] = (df['SUBSET'].str.extractall(r'[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)[^,]*')
                .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join))
```

output:

```
    NAME       SUBSET
0  Apple          ABC
1    Bat  ACD, FI, FE
2    Cat      ABC, AA
```

Alternatively, using `split` as a first step:

```
df['SUBSET'] = (df['SUBSET']
 .str.split(',')
 .explode()
 .str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False)
 .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
)
```

Comment: @ADITYA Did it solve your problem?